# Write return variable to external data

Tags: eigen3

Suppose that I have

```cpp
size_t n = 100;
Eigen::MatrixXd A(n, n);
std::vector<double> x(n);
std::vector<double> b(n);

Eigen::VectorXd B = A * Eigen::Map<const Eigen::VectorXd>(x.data(), n);
std::copy(B.data(), B.data() + n, b.begin());
```

My question is: can I write directly to the memory of the 'external' `b` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Eigen::Map` with a non-const template parameter is writable, so you can simply write:

```
Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd>(b.data(), b.size()).noalias()
      = A * Eigen::Map<const Eigen::VectorXd>(x.data(), n);
```

The `.noalias()` is important to tell Eigen that the left-hand-side does not alias any part of the right-hand-side (otherwise, it would evaluate to a temporary first, producing almost identical instructions to your original code).

Comment: I don't understand the importance of `.noalias()` in this case. According to the documentation ["Matrix multiplication is the only operation in Eigen that assumes aliasing by default,"](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicAliasing.html). In view of this, since we are not performing any matrix multiplication here, I am not sure how the additional `.noalias()` would make a difference.

Comment: @RHertel Matrix-vector-multiplication is a special case of matrix-multiplication, but it also assumes aliasing by default.

Comment: Oh, right, of course. I had overlooked the `A * `part after the equal sign. Thanks for the explanation.